# Find Number of Unique Values in Table

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table with four columns:

PartNumber, ValvePartNumber, ActuatorPartNumber, Price

I want to find the number of distinct prices for each combination of ValvePartNumber and ActuatorPartNumber.

This is using SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can combine `COUNT(DISINTCT)` and `GROUP BY` to accomplish this.

```
SELECT ValuePartNumber, ActuatorPartNumber, COUNT(DISTINCT Price) AS Prices
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY ValuePartNumber, ActuatorPartNumber
```

Comment: I did not know that you could use COUNT and DISTINCT together like that. That makes it nice and simple. Thanks